# Cannot make a static reference / Cannot use "this" in static context Dilemma

Tags: java, android, static, scope, android-context

I'm attempting to create an Android application that accomplishes the following: it sends an initial survey question via text message to a group of recipients (numbers stored in an array). Then for each response it gets, it sends that participant the next question in the series. This is the first Android development I've ever done, so my apologies if this is obvious!

I have the sendQuestion function defined as such within my MainActivity:

```
public void sendQuestion(String number, int question)
{
    //necessary setup for sending a text message
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    PendingIntent sentPI;
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

    //actually sends the text message
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, questions[question], sentPI, null);
}
```

Then I'm attempting to call the sendQuestion function from within my SmsReceiver class:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        for (int i=0;i<MainActivity.numbers.length;i++)
        {
            MainActivity.sendQuestion(MainActivity.numbers[i], MainActivity.survey_location[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The first error I get is that I can't make a static reference to the non-static method `sendQuestion` from type `MainActivity`. As a fix, I thought I'd try changing `sendQuestion` to be a static method. But then I get the error on `sendPI` within `sendQuestion` that I cannot use `this` in a static context.

Is there a way I can get `MainActivity`'s context OR keep `sendQuestion` non-static without conflicting with whichever one I don't change? And what's the best way to avoid this type of problem in general in the future?

Comment: First thing to check: do you understand what `static` *means*? Do you understand why you're getting an error? Given the code sample, it sounds like you've got altogether too many static variables to start with...

Comment: Non static method can not can not be referenced from a static context!

Comment: Regardless of your present difficulty, Android is probably not the right platform for this task.  You are likely to find that if you do any real volume, your mobile provider will cut you off or at least throttle your messaging - a paid SMS gateway is the proper tool for such a task.

Comment: Can you put the whole code ? And learning basics of Java is really helpful before diving into the world of Android development.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, gang. 

@ChrisStratton - good point, but it's going to be a pretty small group of people and not a lot of messages to each, so I'm not really worried about issues with the carrier.

Comment: @JonSkeet & 1011 - you're both absolutely right, and in an ideal world I would take the time to learn more about Java before doing this. Unfortunately, I'm on a weirdly tight schedule, so I'm just doing the best I can with what I can throw together.

Comment: @richardmherndon: This really isn't going to scale to building a whole app... just ploughing on without understanding some of the really *core* parts of Java is going to cost you time. Every time you don't understand something, it's going to take longer to fix the issue than it would if you took just half a day to learn the basics as best you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended way would be to make utility methods like sendQuestion static in a different class and send the context as a parameter to the method. In that way you can access this method from any where and you just need to pass the context as additional parameter to the method.

Comment: This worked! Then I was able to just call `context` from within OnReceive and everything's going smoothly now. Thanks so much @Madala!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you construct the `SmsReceiver`.  If you do this from somewhere in `MainActivity`, you could add a `MainActivity` parameter to the constructor:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public SmsReceiver(MainActivity activity) {
        super();
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

and in `MainActivity`, when you create the new `SmsReceiver`, it could be something like

```
recv = new SmsReceiver(this);
```

and then, instead of `MainActivity.sendQuestion`, you'd call `mActivity.sendQuestion`.  I don't know enough about your program, so the details may differ.  The main thing, though, is that your `SmsReceiver` needs a reference to a `MainActivity` **object** so that it knows what object to call `sendQuestion` for; therefore, the rest of the program needs a way to give it the reference it needs.  And giving it the information as a constructor parameter is probably the simplest way to accomplish that.

Comment: So I did this, and the code was able to build without problem. But the app crashes as soon as it receives a text message, with the logcat saying: `Unable to start receiver appname.SmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?  The LogCat will tell you what line the exception is being thrown on (but you might have to look down a ways to find it; look for something that says "caused by").

Comment: I actually ended up getting the app to work with Madala's suggestion, which seems to be a little simpler (at least for my purposes). Thanks for your help though!